# How to set content-type in Rest Client step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using the Rest Client as below,

[image: Error]

But every time I have the same error message

> HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

When I use the same config in postman client, (Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded) I've success message.

What I have to do ?

Comment: How did you get the content-type in header section? By clicking on get fields step or manually you have written it?

Comment: Like this "Header = application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be somewhat reviving an old question, however:

In the headers tab on the Rest Client step the field column refers to a data field in your input stream to this step.  The Name refers to the Name of the header.  In the screenshot you've added you're trying to add a header called `${CONTENT_TYPE}` with the value as contained in your stream field `content-type`.

Your first step appears to be a data grid. That grid needs to be supplying a field that you reference as your `content-type` header.  If it can't come from that grid you need to inject a step (something like `Add Constant`) that will add the `content-type` header.

Hope it helps.